# Multiple folders, different versions, same SVN

Tags: version-control, tortoisesvn, visual-studio-2017

At my workplace, I have managed to install and use locally Tortoise svn, to easier trak the implementation of the tools. For the new projects, it's easy because I start from scratch with the version control.

Now, for the past projects, I have copied the entire folder to keep a versioning.
It looks like this:

TempProject 20.07.2017
TempProject 21.07.2017
TempProject 22.07.2017
....

Is there a possibility to integrate all this changes with Tortoise?
Meaning , I want to have a base, than commits,  for each version

Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve it.

I copied, one by one, the content from each folder (TempProject 22.07.2017 etc.) into my working copy folder, then I opened the project and committed the changes.

Maybe it's not the most efficient method, but at least it wasn't very complicated